Rotating a conic, in terms of the conic constant and radius of curvature
I am trying to calculate the surface shape of an optical component $z$ given its radius of curvature $R$, conic constant $K$, and angle of rotation $\theta$. I'm only considering relatively small values of $\theta$, i.e., the function will not be rotated so much that it isn't a function anymore. I start with the equation
$$
z = \frac{x^2}{R+\sqrt{R^2 - (K+1)x^2}} \tag{1}
$$
To get the rotated surface, I understand that I need to use the following:
$$
x' = x\cos\theta + z\sin\theta\\ \tag{2}
$$
$$
z' = -x\sin\theta + z\cos\theta \tag{3}
$$
so basically I would like to get $z'$ as a function of $x'$ and nothing else. Substituting eq 1 into 2, I can write
$$
0 = -x' + x\cos\theta + \frac{x^2\sin\theta}{R+\sqrt{R^2-(K+1)x^2}} \tag{4}
$$
and if I get $x$ as a function of $x'$, then I can get $z'(x')$ easily. I got a solution by throwing this at Mathematica, but I wanted to compare this result to if I rotated the points $(x,z)$ to $(x',z')$ directly using eqs 2 and 3. This plot shows that they're off by a bit for some reason:
Plot comparing rotated conics
I thought this meant that the Mathematica solution was incorrect. Instead of using the symbolic solution to eq 4, tried to numerically compute the zeros of it to get $x$, but the result was the same. Is there something wrong with my approach?

It's hard to know exactly what went wrong since you don't provide the Mathematica soln. Be that as it may ... As written, your eqn contains an extraneous factor that complicates solving; better to write:
$$z=\frac1{K+1}\left(R-\sqrt{R^2-(K+1)x^2}\right)\tag{1'}$$
Now, interpreting $(2)$ and $(3)$ as substitutions made into $(1')$, your $(4)$ should be
$$-x\sin\theta+z\cos\theta=\frac1{K+1}\left(R-\sqrt{R^2-(K+1)(x\cos\theta+z\sin\theta)^2}\right)\tag{4'}$$ This should be straightforward to solve for $z$.

BTW: It's perhaps worth noting that the "standard form" equation of your conic is $$x^2,\frac{1 + K}{R^2} ;+; \left(z - \frac{R}{1 + K}\right)^2 ,\frac{(1 + K)^2}{R^2} ;=; 1$$

Thank you. With your help, I solved it by hand and got the answer I expected (also fixing some bugs along the way :) ).

Following $(4')$ in Blue's comment, I collected terms and rewrote the equation as a quadratic:
$$
az^2 + bz + c = 0
$$
where
$$
a = \sin^2\theta + (k+1)\cos^2\theta\\
b = -2kx\sin\theta\cos\theta-2R\cos\theta\\
c = x^2\cos^2\theta + (k+1)x^2\sin^2\theta+2Rx\sin\theta
$$
which gives the solution for $z$, the rotated conic surface.
